# How do I create a relation with neo4jdb (python)

Tags: python, neo4j

unfortunately the sparce documentation https://github.com/jakewins/neo4jdb-python
misses the most important point about a graph db - how do I create a relation between 2 nodes?

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin is just using Cypher, the query language of Neo4j.

You can look here for the complete documentation of cypher:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-query-lang.html

The following query will create a relation for example:

```
MATCH (a:Person),(b:Person)
WHERE a.name = 'Node A' AND b.name = 'Node B'
CREATE (a)-[r:RELTYPE]->(b)
RETURN r
```

Answer (score 1):

To be (overly) clear,

```
import neo4j

connection = neo4j.connect("http://localhost:7474")
cursor = connection.cursor()

q = """
    CREATE (:User {name:{0}})-[:FRIEND]->(:User {name:{1}})                
    """

cursor.execute(q, 'Alice', 'Bob')
connection.commit()
```

This will create two nodes with label User and name properties Alice and Bob and a relationship of type FRIEND between the two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A classic RTFM (read the fine manual): [`DELETE statement in Cypher`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-delete.html)

update:
for creates read http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-create.html#_create_relationships

Comment: No I think it is a read the question problem. B) neo4jdb (python!) documentation has a direct create node function, but the create relation functionality must go through Cypher.